# WSE 3.0 failed parsing the policy document

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, wse

I am working on WebService Authentication with UsernameToken in WSE 3.0 using asp.net mvc in VS 2012. I created a sample application for authorized login. Error i get is *"Failed parsing the policy document."* on      MyWebService.SetPolicy("ClientPolicy"); block of code

here's my code.

```
        webRef.COREEnvelopeRealTimeResponse respObj = new webRef.COREEnvelopeRealTimeResponse();
        webRef.ServiceWse MyWebService = new webRef.ServiceWse();
        webRef.CoreEnvelopeRealTimeRequest obj = new webRef.CoreEnvelopeRealTimeRequest();
        obj.PayloadType = "X12_270_Request_005010X279A1";
        obj.ProcessingMode = "Real Time";
        obj.PayloadID = "f81d4fae-7dec-11d0-a765-00a0c91e6bf6";            
        obj.SenderID = "HETS User";
        obj.ReceiverID = "HETS Admin";
        obj.CORERuleVersion = "2.2.0";
        obj.Payload = "<![CDATA[ISA*00* *00* *ZZ*NEHEN780 *ZZ*NEHEN003 ...IEA*1*000000031]]";



        // Create the username token
        const string Username = "MyUsername";
        const string Password = "MyPassword";
        UsernameToken MyToken = new UsernameToken(Username, Password,PasswordOption.SendPlainText);


        MyWebService.SetClientCredential(MyToken);
        MyWebService.UseDefaultCredentials = false;             
        MyWebService.SetPolicy("ClientPolicy");

        respObj = MyWebService.SendRealTimeRequest(obj);
        MyWebService.SendRealTimeRequest(obj);
        //Response.Write(respObj);
```

i also defined < Policy > named "ClientPolicy" in my wse3policyCache.config. Here's how i used it

```
  <extensions>
<extension name="usernameOverTransportSecurity" type="Microsoft.Web.Services3.Design.UsernameOverTransportAssertion, Microsoft.Web.Services3, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
<extension name="requireActionHeader" type="Microsoft.Web.Services3.Design.RequireActionHeaderAssertion, Microsoft.Web.Services3, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

```
<policy name="ClientPolicy">
<usernameOverTransportSecurity />
<requireActionHeader />
```

i checked for solution provided in msdn site:- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b5e9abe9-4b7b-40f7-bb72-5cc6871ac179/failed-parsing-the-policy-document?forum=asmxandxml but its not working in my case.

thanks in advance